# How do I make the administrative UI feel like Joomla?

Tags: theming, 7

I am working on a way to make a node/add/article page like joomla but but by now I haven't got any remarkable result. 
I've written this code to hide a part and print it in another part:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['revision_information']['#type'] = 'hidden';
}
```

but I need to di it in preprosess time in order to have more performance.
so I use this one:

in .module file:

```
function template_preprocess_article_node_form(&$variables) {
  if (!module_exists('nodeformcols')) {
      hide($variables['form']['additional_settings']);
   }
}
```

in article-node-form.tpl.php

```
<div class="node-add-wrapper clear-block">
  <div class="node-column-sidebar">
    <?php if($sidebar): ?>
      <?php print render($sidebar); print_r($variables['form']['comment_settings']);//['additional_settings'])?>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
```

but I don't have access to all field in this way.
any alternative or simpler approach will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You were going in the right direction with:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['revision_information']['#type'] = 'hidden';
}
```

However, you have a bug in that code. The code above will modify *every* form. Instead, use [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) to target the specific form.

Comment: as I want to make change in theme I think it could be wrong and I  decided to do it in preprocess time. Is it possibe to change theme by using this function?